# Sonar Lint Objective C in connected Mode

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

Does the connected mode for sonar lint CLI work with SonarQube 5.6.x server that has the commercial objective C plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently no. the C/C++/Objective C plugin is not supported. But this is something we are working on.

Comment: Awesome Thank you

Comment: anybody with any news on this?

Comment: @Julien H. Any open source plugin for the objective c?